# Read file using input redirection, and then accept input using keyboard

Tags: c, redirect, input, stdin

I am trying to make a program that will read data in from a text file using input redirection, and then display a menu which will take input from the user using the keyboard.  The issue is that stdin is set to read from the file and will not allow the user to use the keyboard.  Does anyone know how to change the input source from the file to the keyboard in the code?  I am using C

Comment: Do you redirect the input streams programatically, or is the program started with redirected streams?

Comment: The program is started with redirected streams i.e. ./a.out < input.txt.  Also if I was to use freopen, which parameters would redirect the input to the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting `stdin`, you can open the text file using `fopen` and then read from it using `fread`.

And then read from `stdin` (the keyboard, in your case) like before.

Comment: The requirement for the program is that the data is read using input redirection